# ggmap with geom_map superimposed

Tags: r, dictionary, ggplot2, ggmap

```
library(sp)
library(spdep)
library(ggplot2)
library(ggmap)
library(rgdal)
```

Get and fiddle with data:

```
nc.sids <- readShapePoly(system.file("etc/shapes/sids.shp", package="spdep")[1],ID="FIPSNO", proj4string=CRS("+proj=longlat +ellps=clrk66"))
nc.sids=spTransform(nc.sids,CRS("+init=epsg:4326"))
```

Get background map from stamen.com, plot, looks nice:

```
ncmap = get_map(location=as.vector(bbox(nc.sids)),source="stamen",maptype="toner",zoom=7)
ggmap(ncmap)
```

Create a data frame with long,lat,Z, and plot over the map and a blank plot:

```
ncP = data.frame(coordinates(nc.sids),runif(nrow(nc.sids)))
colnames(ncP)=c("long","lat","Z")

ggmap(ncmap)+geom_point(aes(x=long,y=lat,col=Z),data=ncP)
ggplot()+geom_point(aes(x=long,y=lat,col=Z),data=ncP)
```

give it some unique ids called 'id' and fortify (with vitamins and iron?)

```
nc.sids@data[,1]=1:nrow(nc.sids)
names(nc.sids)[1]="id"
ncFort = fortify(nc.sids)
```

Now, my map and my limits, I want to plot the 74 birth rate:

```
myMap = geom_map(aes(fill=BIR74,map_id=id),map=ncFort,data=nc.sids@data)
Limits = expand_limits(x=ncFort$long,y=ncFort$lat)
```

and on a blank plot I can:

```
ggplot() + myMap + Limits
```

but on a ggmap I can't:

```
ggmap(ncmap) + myMap + Limits
# Error in eval(expr, envir, enclos) : object 'lon' not found
```

Some versions:

```
> packageDescription("ggplot2")$Version
[1] "0.9.0"
> packageDescription("ggmap")$Version
[1] "2.0"
```

I can add geom_polygon to ggplot or ggmap and it works as expected. So something is up with geom_map....

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The error message is, I think, the result of an inheritance issue. Typically, it comes about when different data frames are used in subsequent layers.

In ggplot2, every layer inherits default aes mappings set globally in the initial call to `ggplot`. For instance, `ggplot(data = data, aes(x = x, y = y))` sets x and y mappings globally so that all subsequent layers expect to see `x` and `y` in whatever data frame has been assigned to them. If `x` and `y` are not present, an error message similar to the one you got results. [See here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5415132/object-not-found-error-with-ggplot2-when-adding-shape-aesthetic) for a similar problem and a range of solutions.

In your case, it's not obvious because the first call is to `ggmap` - you can't see the mappings nor how they are set because `ggmap` is all nicely wrapped up. Nevertheless, `ggmap` calls `ggplot` somewhere, and so default aesthetic mappings must have been set somewhere in the initial call to `ggmap`. It follows then that `ggmap` followed by `geom_map` without taking account of inheritance issues results in the error.

So, Kohske's advice in the earlier post applies - "you need to nullify the lon aes in geom_map when you use a different dataset". Without knowing too much about what has been set or how they've been set, it's probably simplest to globber the lot by adding `inherit.aes = FALSE` to the second layer - the call to `geom_map`.

Note that you don't get the error message with `ggplot() + myMap + Limits` because no aesthetics have been set in the ggplot call.

In what follows, I'm using R version 2.15.0, ggplot2 version 0.9.1, and ggmap version 2.1. I use your code almost exactly, except for the addition of `inherit.aes = FALSE` in the call to `geom_map`. That one small change allows `ggmap` and `geom_map` to be superimposed:

```
library(sp)
library(spdep)
library(ggplot2)
library(ggmap)
library(rgdal)

#Get and fiddle with data:
nc.sids <- readShapePoly(system.file("etc/shapes/sids.shp", package="spdep")[1],ID="FIPSNO", proj4string=CRS("+proj=longlat +ellps=clrk66"))
nc.sids=spTransform(nc.sids,CRS("+init=epsg:4326"))

#Get background map from stamen.com, plot, looks nice:
ncmap = get_map(location=as.vector(bbox(nc.sids)),source="stamen",maptype="toner",zoom=7)
ggmap(ncmap)

#Create a data frame with long,lat,Z, and plot over the map and a blank plot:
ncP = data.frame(coordinates(nc.sids),runif(nrow(nc.sids)))
colnames(ncP)=c("long","lat","Z")

ggmap(ncmap)+geom_point(aes(x=long,y=lat,col=Z),data=ncP)
ggplot()+geom_point(aes(x=long,y=lat,col=Z),data=ncP)

#give it some unique ids called 'id' and fortify (with vitamins and iron?)
nc.sids@data[,1]=1:nrow(nc.sids)
names(nc.sids)[1]="id"
ncFort = fortify(nc.sids)

#Now, my map and my limits, I want to plot the 74 birth rate:
myMap = geom_map(inherit.aes = FALSE, aes(fill=BIR74,map_id=id), map=ncFort,data=nc.sids@data)
Limits = expand_limits(x=ncFort$long,y=ncFort$lat)

# and on a blank plot I can:
ggplot() + myMap + Limits

# but on a ggmap I cant:
ggmap(ncmap) + myMap + Limits
```

The result from the last line of code is:

[image]

Comment: I get "Error in validDetails.polygon(x) : 'x' and 'y' and 'id' must all be same length" if I add inherit.aes=FALSE to myMap in the example above.

Comment: @Spacedman I've edited my answer to include the code and the result. The code is almost exactly your code except for the addition `inherit.aes = FALSE` in the `geom_map` call.

Comment: I updated ggplot2 and ggmap to those versions and now ggplot2 is totally broke. The first example in geom_point produces a plot with no points, just sets the axes, the gray b/g, and nothing. From an R --vanilla with no other packages loaded. Maybe an R version thing (2.14.2...). Grr.

Comment: Yeah, seems to work with 2.15, weird things with R 2.14. Upgrade time.

Comment: @Spacedman I should have mentioned the R version - I seem to remember something similar with R2.14. I've re-writted the post adding explanation of the inheritance of aesthetics issue.

Comment: inherit.aes = FALSE - arrrrgh