# using ggmap and ggplotly

Tags: r, ggplot2, plotly, ggmap

I am trying to use ggmap with ggplotly, and I am having trouble making the packages work together. A search for the error message got me [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10930737/ggmap-with-geom-map-superimposed). However, I am not sure how the aes inheritance is/could be a problem. The strange thing is that 'myPlot' created with ggmap works just fine in RStudio, but cannot connect to ggplotly. The map data is from [here](http://www.r-bloggers.com/google-maps-and-ggmap/).

Is it possible to get these two packages working together? (By the way, I cannot tag this as ggplotly, I dont think that package has been referenced on SO before.)

**Code**

```
lapply(list("ggplot2", "ggmap", "mapproj", "RCurl", "RJSONIO", "plyr"), 
       require, character.only=TRUE)
# install.packages("devtools")
library("devtools")
# install_github("plotly", "ropensci")
library(plotly)

mapImageData1 <- get_map(location = c(lon = -0.016179, lat = 51.538525),
                         color = "color",
                         source = "google",
                         maptype = "satellite",
                         zoom = 17)

myMap = ggmap(mapImageData1,
      extent = "device",
      ylab = "Latitude",
      xlab = "Longitude")

py <- plotly("RgraphingAPI", "ektgzomjbx")
res <- py$ggplotly(gg = p_map)
```

**Error Message**

> res <- py$ggplotly(gg = p_map)
>       Error in eval(expr, envir, enclos) : object 'lon' not found

Answer (score 2, accepted):

just replace within your existing dataframe the column names for latitude and longitude like this at the start

(if p_map is your dataframe)

```
setnames(p_map, "Latitude", "lat")
setnames(p_map, "Longitude", "lon")
```