# How to plot SpatialLinesDataFrame feature map over Google maps

Tags: r, google-maps, ggmap

I'm trying to plot a line layer over Google maps.

Data

```
> dput(map)
new("SpatialLinesDataFrame"
        , data = structure(list(att = c(463643, 2291491, 315237340, 10348934, 
309845150, 674351, 58057, 55962, 302861, 1405635)), .Names = "att",     row.names = c(NA, 
10L), class = "data.frame")
    , lines = list(<S4 object of class structure("Lines", package = "sp")>, 
    <S4 object of class structure("Lines", package = "sp")>, 
    <S4 object of class structure("Lines", package = "sp")>, 
    <S4 object of class structure("Lines", package = "sp")>, 
    <S4 object of class structure("Lines", package = "sp")>, 
    <S4 object of class structure("Lines", package = "sp")>, 
    <S4 object of class structure("Lines", package = "sp")>, 
    <S4 object of class structure("Lines", package = "sp")>, 
    <S4 object of class structure("Lines", package = "sp")>, 
    <S4 object of class structure("Lines", package = "sp")>)
    , bbox = structure(c(50.497608475813, 26.1186426230732, 50.6164182652142, 
26.2649832975207), .Dim = c(2L, 2L), .Dimnames = list(c("x", 
"y"), c("min", "max")))
    , proj4string = new("CRS"
    , projargs = "+proj=longlat +ellps=WGS84 +towgs84=0,0,0,-0,-0,-0,0 +no_defs"
)
)
```

Approach

```
library(rgdal)
library(ggmap)

gmap <- get_map(location=rowMeans(bbox(segMap)), zoom = 11) # get Google map to use as background
```

Variant I

```
plot(map, col = map$att, lwd = 1.5)
plot(gMap)
```

Variant II

```
plot(map, col = map$att, lwd = 1.5)
ggmap(gMap)
```

Problem

Background map is plotted on top of feature map, rather than as background, as a result feature map is not visible.
To clarify, both plot calls ( `plot()` and `ggmap`) work fine independently.
Thank you

Comment: If you really want to use `ggmap`, you should seriously consider also using the functions from `ggplot2`, which `ggmap` is based on (in terms of the syntax) and more importantly, the two packages work together perfectly (have a look at `ggplot2::geom_line()`, `geom_polygon()` and `fortify()`). If you do not want to use ggplot syntax, rather go with the `openstreetmap` package, `rGooglemaps` etc.

Comment: Thanks @maj. Am I right to understand that using ggmap is a way to avoid going the gis route? What solution would you recommend if I were to also wan to do some spatial analysis?

Comment: @jpinelo they are not mutually exclusive. you can add polygon and map layers to a ggmap created ggplot and `dput`s of `sp` objects (as you can see) don't transport well. This SO answer is an OK example http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10930737/ggmap-with-geom-map-superimposed/10940778#10940778

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Something like this?

[image]

```
library(raster)    # for getData(...), also loads sp
library(ggmap)     # for get_map, also loads ggplot2

map <- getData("GADM",country="GBR",level=2)  # SpatialPolygonsDataFrame of UK
map <- map[map$NAME_2=="London",]             # extract London
# this builds a spatialLinesDataFrame object - random walks around London
# you have this already...
set.seed(1)    # for reproducible example
get.coords <- function() {
  do.call(cbind,lapply(rowMeans(bbox(map)),  
                               function(x)cumsum(sample(0.01*(-1:1),50,replace=TRUE))+x))
}
route <- SpatialLines(lapply(1:3,function(i)Lines(list(Line(get.coords())),ID=i)))
route <- SpatialLinesDataFrame(route, data.frame(att=c("A","B","C")))

# you would start here...
gg.df <- do.call(rbind,lapply(route$att, function(x)data.frame(att=x,coordinates(route[route$att==x,]))))

ggmap(get_map(location=rowMeans(bbox(map)),zoom=12)) + 
  geom_path(data=gg.df,  aes(x,y, color=att), size=2)+
  geom_point(data=gg.df, aes(x=x[1], y=y[1]),color="black",size=5)
```

First of all, thanks for trying to include your data. Normally, `dput(...)` is the way to go, but with spatial objects it just isn't useful. You really need to upload the file (or files, usually) somewhere and post a link.

Second, this is not a trivial problem. It's true that `ggmap(...)` produces a ggplot object which can be augmented by adding additional features using `+`, and it's also true that ggplot provides a very powerful `fortify(...)` function for converting SpatialPolygonsDataFrames into something usable by ggplot. But `fortify(...)` does not work with `SpatialLines` objects, so we have to do this explicitly.

So the bulk of this code just creates a SpatialLinesDataFrame with three lines, each of which has a corresponding attribute `att` in the attributes table. This should mimic your example pretty well. As this is a spatial object, all the methods in `sp`, `rgeos`, and so on on will be able to manipulate it.

Now, `ggplot` requires a data.frame with columns corresponding to the aesthetics mapped in the call to `aes(...)`, so here, x and y for the location of the points, and color for the color of the lines. We create that using:

```
gg.df <- do.call(rbind,lapply(route$att, function(x)data.frame(att=x,coordinates(route[route$att==x,]))))
```

which extracts the coordinates for each value of `att` into a list of data.frames and binds these together row-wise.

Having done that, it's a simple matter to add the lines using

```
ggmap(get_map(location=rowMeans(bbox(map)),zoom=12)) + 
  geom_path(data=gg.df,  aes(x,y, color=att), size=2)+
  geom_point(data=gg.df, aes(x=x[1], y=y[1]),color="black",size=5)
```

Note that, (a) you need to use `geom_path(...)`, because `geom_line(...)` will sort the x-axis, and (b) you need to tell `ggplot` that there's a layer-specific dataset (`gg.df`).

Comment: Thank you @jilhoward for a good and detailed answer. It is much appreciated. I'm having trouble understanding `function(x)` (fifth line from the end). Could you please explain that part? Using this I'm getting the error `Error in eval(expr, envir, enclos) : object 'x' not found`.

Comment: `lapply(...)` takes two arguments. The first is a vector or list. The second is a function. `lapply(...)` passes each element, in sequence, in the first argument to the function specified in the second argument, and then assembles the result into a new list. The use of `function(x)...` here just creates a so-called anonymous (un-named) function for the second argument. In your case, does the equivalent of `route$att` exist?

Comment: Thank you @jilhoward, for the Brilliant answer. I understand now. Thank you for the advice re sharing a link to spatial data rather than posting it.