# Temporarily disable aesthetics already defined in ggplot()

Tags: r, ggplot2, aesthetics

We may want to define some global `aes()` for a `ggplot()` graphics, but exclude them in some layers. For instance suppose the following example:

```
foo <- data.frame(x=runif(10),y=runif(10))
bar <- data.frame(x=c(0,1),ymin=c(-.1,.9),ymax=c(.1,1.1))
p <- ggplot(foo,aes(x=x,y=y))+geom_point()
```

Everything is good. However when trying to add the ribbon:

```
p <- p + geom_ribbon(data=bar, aes(x=x,ymin=ymin,ymax=ymax), alpha=.1)
# Error: Discrete value supplied to continuous scale
```

This error happens because we have already defined `y` as a part of global `aes()` that applies also to the `geom_ribbon()`, but the `bar` does not have it.

I have found two possibilities to escape this error, one of them is to remove `y=y` from the original `ggplot(foo,aes(x=x,y=y))`, however every time in the future I need to draw something I should add `y=y` to the `aes()` that is not good.

The other possibility is to add a fake `y` column to `bar`:

```
bar = cbind(bar, y=0)
p <- p + geom_ribbon(data=bar, aes(x=x,ymin=ymin,ymax=ymax), alpha=.1)
```

[image]

Now works good. However I don't like acting so, as it's a fake variable. Is there any way to temporarily disable the already defined `aes()` in `ggplot()` when calling the `geom_ribbon()`?

Comment: How about `aes(y=NULL,x=x,ymin=ymin,ymax=ymax)`?

Comment: As @ErnestA said, you can unmap aesthetics by setting them to `NULL` in a particular layer.

Comment: @ErnestA why not put your comment as an answer ?

Comment: @agstudy I'm pretty busy at the moment. Feel free to write an answer yourself.

Comment: Try `inherit.aes = FALSE` when using a new data set.  See answers and comments [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5415132/object-not-found-error-with-ggplot2-when-adding-shape-aesthetic) and [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10930737/ggmap-with-geom-map-superimposed)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As said in the comments by @ErnestA, we can unmap the aesthetics by setting them to NULL

```
      aes(y=NULL,x=x,ymin=ymin,ymax=ymax)
```

PS: For the legend you can now override aesthetic by `aes.override`

Comment: Where is `aes.override` documented, or can you provide an example?  Thanks.